# Transparent Tinted Plastic with Chrome Finish Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Does anyone know how to make this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Byra_SngQZw

I've tried using:
transparent with glossy and layer weight facing node,
glass with glossy and layer weight facing node,
glass with principled metallic and layer weight facing node,
and many other variations but I can't make it exactly like that.

I am willing to pay for your time using PayPal.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be very interested in [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/gpu-compatible-thin-film-interference-v2-1-glass-within-glass-absorption/699459) on Blender Artists.